# Drawing formatt

Tags: us20160324086

In reference to the patent: [US20160324086](https://www.google.com/patents/US20160324086)

Please advise file format for attached patent drawings as I am unable to open
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with www.google.com/patents. Others are having it too. There are other sites for searching for patents. [The Lens](https://www.lens.org/lens) is a good one. [Here](https://www.lens.org/lens/patent/US_2016_0324086_A1) is the cited application on The Lens. Also, if you search at [patents.google.com](https://patents.google.com/) you also can find the [application](https://patents.google.com/patent/US20160324086A1/en) with drawings.